# CONCAT or APPEND two Alias columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
SELECT RIGHT(EVAL,2) AS MONTH, EVAL, LEFT(EVAL,4) AS YEAR,
CASE 
    WHEN RIGHT(EVAL,2) < 04 THEN 'Q1'
    WHEN RIGHT(EVAL,2) BETWEEN '04' AND '06' THEN 'Q2'
    WHEN RIGHT(EVAL,2) BETWEEN '06' AND '09' THEN 'Q3'
    WHEN RIGHT(EVAL,2) BETWEEN '09' AND '12' THEN 'Q4'
    END AS QTR
FROM [CREDIT CARD]
```

**PRESENT OUTPUT**

```
   MONTH  EVAL   YEAR   QTR
    07     201807 2018   Q3
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
MONTH EVAL   YEAR   QTR  EVALQTR
07    201807  2018   Q3   2018Q3
```

EVAL is the period in the format 201802, 201904. I have broken down EVAL into month, year, and quarter(Case). 
I want the final output to be YEAR+Quarter i.e. 2019Q2, 2018Q1. I am not able to APPEND OR CONCAT YEAR AND QTR COLUMN as they are aliases. Every time I use concat or append function get the error that YEAR and QTR are invalid columns.Need solution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems simplest as:

```
select concat(left(eval, 4), 'Q',
              datename(quarter, convert(date, eval + '01'))
             ) as evalqtr
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cdfa596f8eab0ee5a531119c6101fa4b) is a db<>fiddle.